# Delete query does not work in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

This is strange but my SQL Server does not delete items:

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
Create Procedure DeleteItem @cnm nchar(10)
as
    Begin Transaction 
       Delete From T1 where Cnm = @cnm
       Delete From T2 where Cnm = @cnm

       if @@ERROR <> 0 
       Begin
          Commit
       End
       Else
       Begin
           RollBack
       End
```

and when I run this query in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Exec DeleteItem '1111111111'
```

it returns in the `Messages` pane:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
(1 row(s) affected)
```

but when I get data from that tables the deleted record still exist!

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You should probably be checking for errors on *both* deletes, not just the second one.

Comment: You should be using `try...catch`. Not checking `@@error`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`@@ERROR`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188790.aspx) returns `0` if the previous Transact-SQL statement encountered no errors.

Change your `IF` condition

```
if @@ERROR = 0
Commit
else 
....
```